# resolver programação

Tags: javascript

preciso de ajuda nas linhas abaixo onde aparece video e imagem quando digito foto

```js
var nota = document.getElementById("text").value;

function limparimg() {
  document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = "";
}

function limparvid() {
  document.getElementById("video").innerHTML = "";
}

function videoof() {

  var video = document.getElementById("video");
  var video = video.className;
  var iFrame = document.getElementById("caixa");
  iFrame.src = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + video;
}


function mostracav() {
  var foto = "<img src=http://www.ficasimples.com.br/eliza/cavit.jpg>";
  new Array(10);


  document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = foto;
}

function talk() {
  var nota = document.getElementById("text").value;
  var vid = "vid";
  if (nota == "vid") {
    videoof();
  }


  var qya = "foto";
  if (nota == "foto") {
    mostracav();
  }
}
```

```html
<h2>My First JavaScript</h2>
<div id="video" class="UJAwNkhbYWM"><iframe id="caixa" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="200" width="250"></iframe> </div>
<div id="div"><img id="img"></div>
<br> Enter Text To Play:
<input id="text" value="">&nbsp;
<br>
<button class="btn btn-success" onclick="talk()">Atenas
    Falar!</button>

<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = Date()">
    Click me to display Date and Time.</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Pode verificar porque aparece  o video e imagem quando digito foto.

Comment: Este array solto não faz sentido `var foto="<img src=http://www.ficasimples.com.br/eliza/cavit.jpg>";new Array(10);`, testei aqui e só apareceu a foto, o iframe não foi atualizado, deve estar se confundindo.

Comment: Olá Silezia! Eu coloquei uma resposta, mas não sei se entendi realmente o que você perguntou - se puder, por favor esclareça melhor sua intenção [editando](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/210028/edit) a pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que o problema seja você estar usando dois divs diferentes para cada elemento. Se a intenção é mostrar **ou** o vídeo **ou** a foto, você pode usar o mesmo div, e trocar o conteúdo deles pelo javascript.

Dê uma olhada no exemplo abaixo:

```js
var nota = document.getElementById("text").value;

function limpar() {
  document.getElementById("video-foto").innerHTML = "";
}

function videoof() {
    limpar();
    var video = document.getElementById("video-foto");
    var ifr = document.createElement("iFrame");
    ifr.setAttribute("id", "caixa");
    ifr.setAttribute("height", "200");
    ifr.setAttribute("width", "250");
    video.appendChild(ifr);
    ifr.src = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + video.className;
}

function mostracav() {
    limpar();
    var foto = "<img src=http://www.ficasimples.com.br/eliza/cavit.jpg>";
    document.getElementById("video-foto").innerHTML = foto;
}

function talk() {
    var nota = document.getElementById("text").value;
    if (nota == "vid") {
    videoof();
    }

    if (nota == "foto") {
        mostracav();
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>                                                                    
<h2>My First JavaScript</h2>
<div id="video-foto" class="UJAwNkhbYWM">
</div>
<br> Enter Text To Play:
<input id="text" value="">&nbsp;
<br>
<button class="btn btn-success" onclick="talk()">Atenas
    Falar!</button>

<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = Date()">
    Click me to display Date and Time.</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
</body>
<script src="./javascript.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Resolveu  o problema. Era bem isto que eu queria.

Comment: @Silezia legal - quando uma resposta lhe serve, e você tem sua pergunta resolvida, você pode marca-la como aceita, clicando na marca de verificação ao lado da resposta. Veja mais no [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) como o site funciona. :)